# How can I make navigation item searchbar fully visible/hidden, when I scroll down/up?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I can make search bar in navigation item partially visible when I Scroll the tableView, But I want only fully visible or fully hidden.
I couldn't make searchBar partially visible in any other iOS Apps like Notes, WhatsApp, Telegram etc.
I guess I can make this in scrollViewDidScroll delegate.
But, is there a way to achieve this by default?

[image: Before I do little scrolling]
[image: After I did little scrolling]

Comment: Your description is confusing. Do you want your search bar to behave just like it does in Notes, WhatsApp, and Telegram or do you want your search bar to behave differently than Notes, WhatsApp, and Telegram?

Comment: Yes, you are right. @HangarRash

Comment: I'm not able to make the searchbar like screenshot2 in those application.
But, When I assign searchController to navigationitem search in my code, I can make the searchbar like screenshot2.
@HangarRash

Comment: I figured it out. 
I used tableview inside UIViewController.
Once I used UItableviewcontroller, this issue got solved.
Thanks all for trying to help.